# Accessing a custom dispatcher defined in application.conf inside a Scala trait

Tags: scala, akka, dispatcher, executioncontext

I'm doing a few operations on `Future`s inside an `trait`.

```
trait MyTrait {
  //Future based operations 

}
```

Instead of using `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` for my `Future`, I want to use one that is defined in my `application.conf`.

```
akka {
  my-batch-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 10
      parallelism-factor = 2.0
      parallelism-max = 10
    }
    throughput = 20
  }
}
```

Inside my actor I can do a lookup to get the execution context.

```
  implicit val ec = context.system.dispatchers.lookup("akka.my-batch-dispatcher")
```

Now sure how to do this inside my trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as abstract implicit value of the trait:

```
trait MyTrait {
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext
  //Future based operations 

}
```

Then the code the implement the trait should make sure to provide the ExecutionContext. If that is an Actor you may do something like:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with MyTrait {
  implicit val ec = context.system.dispatchers.lookup("akka.my-batch-dispatcher")
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("hello back at you")
    case _       => println("huh?")
  }
}
```

I didn't test it but I think this should work.